# Having problems creating a new Access record using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

A little background on my skills. In 2006 I taught my self to use VB6 to communicate to an Access Database. I had success and wrote a couple of handy databases for myself through tutorials and message boards. Now I would like to make another but a lot has changed. Needless to say I'm a novice that has become a beginner.

On form load, I see my data in a datagridview. When I click the row header on the datagridview it loads the data to text boxes. This all works how I'd like it to.

My problem is adding a new record. I have searched this site, found a few suggestion that I thought might work, I implemented them and can't get them to work. The Commit Button is where I want this to happen. If someone out there can help that would be fantastic. My Code is as follows:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection        'THE CONNECTION OBJECT
    Dim dbProvider As String                    'HOLDS THE PROVIDER
    Dim dbSource As String                      'HOLDS THE DATA SOURCE
    Dim MyFolder As String                      'HOLDS THE DATABASE FOLDER
    Dim TheDatabase As String                   'HOLDS THE DATABASE NAME
    Dim FullDatabasePath As String              'HOLDS THE DATABASE PATH
    Dim ds As New DataSet                       'HOLDS THE DataSet OBJECT
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter            'HOLDS THE DataAdapter OBJECT
    Dim sql As String                           'HOLDS THE SQL STRING


Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.PV_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PVdbDataSet1.PV_Table)

    'SET UP THE PROVIDER
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
    TheDatabase = "/PVdb.accdb"
    MyFolder = "C:\Pipe Vault"
    FullDatabasePath = MyFolder & TheDatabase

    'SET THE DATA SOURCE
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

    'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    'OPEN THE DATABASE
    con.Open()

    'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
    sql = "SELECT * FROM PV_table"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "PV_Table")

    'Close THE DATABASE  '
    con.Close()
    'MessageBox.Show("Database is now closed")
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowHeaderMouseClick
    'LOADS TEXTBOXS WITH DATA FROM DATAGRID OBJECT
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    txtLocation.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    txtProjectName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    TxtPipeDate.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    txtPipeNumber.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    txtPipeSize.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
    txtAproxFootage.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
    txtInstallDate.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
End Sub

Private Sub TxtPipeDate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtPipeDate.Click
    MonthCalendar1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub MonthCalendar1_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected
    TxtPipeDate.Text = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart
    MonthCalendar1.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(1) = txtLocation.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(2) = txtProjectName.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(3) = TxtPipeDate.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(4) = txtPipeNumber.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(5) = txtPipeSize.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(6) = txtAproxFootage.Text
    ds.Tables("PV_table").Rows(i).Item(7) = txtInstallDate.Text
    da.Update(ds, "PV_table")

    'MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click

    Dim a As Control

    'ENABLES TEXT BOXES
    For Each a In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
            a.Enabled = True
        End If
    Next

    'CLEARS CONTENTS OF TEXT BOXES
    txtLocation.Clear()
    txtProjectName.Clear()
    TxtPipeDate.Clear()
    txtPipeNumber.Clear()
    txtPipeSize.Clear()
    txtAproxFootage.Clear()
    txtInstallDate.Clear()

    'SETS STATES OF BUTTONS
    btnCommit.Enabled = True
    btnAddNew.Enabled = False
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False
    btnDelete.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Clear.Click
    btnCommit.Enabled = False
    btnAddNew.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = True
    btnDelete.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click


    Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("PV_Table").NewRow()
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    newRow("Location") = txtLocation.Text
    newRow("Project Name") = txtProjectName.Text
    newRow("Pipe Date") = TxtPipeDate
    newRow("Pipe Number") = txtPipeNumber
    newRow("Pipe Size") = txtPipeSize.Text
    newRow("Aprox Footage") = txtAproxFootage.Text
    newRow("Install Date") = txtInstallDate.Text

    ds.Tables("PV_Table").Rows.Add(newRow)
    da.Update(ds, "PV_Table")

End Sub
```

Comment: You just need to create a NewRow (DataTable.NewRow) then fill it with the values from you text (like you do in the update), Add the row to the Rows collection (DataTable.Rows.Add) and call the Adapter Update after creating the CommandBuilder. Search MSDN for examples

Comment: You also closed your connection in your form_load.  You will need to open it again when you do an insert or update.